# Print multiple fields in AWK but split one of them based on a different delimiter

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Is there an easy way to split a field, get the first element from the said split field AND also print other fields in same awk?

I want to modify below such that is works for $2 not just when it's `MCU:123` but also when it's `DISNEY:654` such that $2 returns `MCU` or `DISNEY` depending on the string. Obviously substr was a bad choice there.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print $1,substr($2,1,3)}'
```

**Sample of two fields tab seperated**

```
1  mcu:1234   
2  disney:234
```

**Expected result tab seperated**

```
1  mcu    
2  disney
```

Comment: Probably you need to use `split($2, a, /:/); print a[1];` to split using `:` and get first field. You can also do `sub(/:.*/, "", $2)`

Comment: @PhilCoulson, could you please confirm if lines `+------+------------+` OR `|    ` are real lines in your samples?

Comment: How do you feel about Tahiti?

Comment: @EdMorton Glad you asked. It's a magical place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cut -d: -f1 file
1       mcu
2       disney
```

or if the real file is more convoluted than the example in your question then maybe this will do what you really need:

```
$ awk -F'[\t:]' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2}' file
1       mcu
2       disney
```

Comment: This is cool,  how exactly does `\t:`. I have mostly seen `\t`

Comment: the FS is a regexp and `[abc...]` in a regexp is a bracket expression thats just a list of characters that could match one char in  the input.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/:.*/,"",$2)} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `split` function of `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {split($2,arr,":");$2=arr[1]} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I was surprisingly closer than I gave my myself credit so throwing this in there as an alternative.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print $1,substr($2,1,index($2,":")-1)}'
```

Note that this fails if $2 isn't : delimited. For my use case, $2 would be : delimited by design and even if wasn't, I only need to perform this for values in $2 that do have : in them. To account for that, I could modify this to

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{if($2 ~ ":") print $1,substr($2,1,index($2,":")-1)}'
```

Other solutions are more scalable and possibly more performant.